# Use icacls.exe to set special folder permissions for a domain user

Tags: windows, cmd, icacls

I have a folder and I wonder how I can use icacls.exe to set its permissions to be special for a certain user so it looks like below?

[image]

Comment: Don't double-post! [Set folder special permissions using cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49673903)

Comment: @aschipfl thanks, deleted the other question as this one is more specified.

Comment: Using `icacls /?` provides the information you need to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's like the 'modify' permission set, except you've swapped 'Delete' for 'Delete subfolders and files'. You can grant these individually starting e.g. from the read-execute permission set

```
icacls folder /grant domain\user:(RX,WD,AD,WA,WEA,DC)
```

or `/grant:r` if you want to overwrite rather than add to any existing permissions.

Comment: Thank you, that did it except that the delete option should be unticked and the delete subfolders should be ticked as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQDap.png. Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: D'oh, I hadn't spotted they were mixed up. Will have another look.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows10 with PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Temp> icacls.exe .\user_identity /reset
PS C:\Temp> icacls.exe .\user_identity /grant:R domain_name\ejdemire:R
PS C:\Temp> icacls.exe .\user_identity /inheritance:r
PS C:\Temp> sftp -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -oCiphers=aes256-cbc -i user_identity -oKexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 sftp_user@192.x.x.x
```